# Impossible to add a script to cron

Tags: debian, cron, cron.daily

I am trying to add a script to cron jobs to be played daily.

I tried multiple things but no one seems to work.

First I tried to add a script in cron.daily: It s not triggered.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/foo/
/usr/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="bar.foo.Main" > ~/foo.log
```

Then I tried to add a line in crontab using **vi crontab** same thing

```
17 *    * * *   root    cd ~/foo/ && /usr/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="bar.foo.Main" > ~/foo.log
```

Then I tried to use crontab -e and add the same line than before : nothing.

It s the first time I tried to launch a periodic script... Is there something to restart?

PS : Why **vi crontab** and **crontab -e** don't display the same thing?

Comment: for your script, did you make it executable `chmod +x yourscript.sh`

Comment: nope he wasn't! I am going to try it like that. Does it have to be .sh? Other scripts in cron.daily don't have extension

Comment: No it doesn't, that was just an example as I don't know your filename..

Comment: OK. Is there some log file I could have seen that it was a right problem?

Comment: I believe it's `/var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your script is executable

```
chmod +x yourscript.sh
```